# SignatureValue without Id attribute

Tags: xades4j

When I sign an XML document I get:

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="xmldsig-f62dafae-6983-4b97-9b52-3f24c6960c43">
    ....
    <ds:SignatureValue Id="xmldsig-f62dafae-6983-4b97-9b52-3f24c6960c43-sigvalue">
         VpJzFiW62NK2ytlUkAYF....
    </ds:SignatureValue>
    ....
</ds:Signature>
```

Is it possible to get ds:SignatureValue without the Id attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to control the presence/value of that (and other) IDs, since it's [hard-coded on the signer class](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/blob/master/src/main/java/xades4j/production/SignerBES.java#L282). These IDs may be needed by some qualifying properties, hence being added.